# spring roo pattern vs repository pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, persistence, spring-roo

I am using spring roo for one of my projects. What spring roo does is add persistance methods to existing classes. For example, you can call Person.persist() to save object of type person in database.

I saw another pattern recently. Following is code for that.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}

@Repository
public class CustomerRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Customer c) {
        em.persist(c);
    }
}

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home controller! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        Customer c = new Customer("XXX", "YYY");
        customerRepository.save(c);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

What are pros and cons of each?

Comment: I would have prefer that your final question would be more about the advantages or disadvantages of either approach, because otherwise the answers might be opinionated.

Comment: google activerecord versus repository and if you prefer the repository pattern you can also use this with Roo: see 10.2.2 docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html

Comment: Read the discussion at Roo project about Data access patterns : https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-301